# how to convert VC++ 2005 projects to VC++ 2012 projects in bulk?

Tags: visual-c++

i want to convert around 200 projects from VC++ 2005 to VC++ 2012 projects and build them.

can somebody help me steps i need to follow to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: 1. Open each project in VC++2012. 2. Rebuild the project. 3. If you have any warning or errors, then try to solve them yourself first, and publish here the ones you are unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio will automatically convert your projects from VS2005 to the VS2012 format when you open the solution/project. Notice that an important change is that in VS2012 MSBuild is used instead of VSBuild for building the VC++ projects.

Depending on the projects you have you may run into some breaking changes that you have to resolve manually. Take a look at [Lessons learned migrating to Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562386/Lessons-learned-migrating-to-Visual-Studio-an) to get an overview of possible problems and things to do.